# How to statistically describe chain-like patterns in bivariate data?

Tags: correlation

I am reading an article that explores correlation between two variables, X and Y. Usually, if the scatter plot show something like this, we can claim that there is a strong correlation of X and Y.

```
Y
|
|              o
|           o o
|          o
|        o o    
|       o
|    o
|  o
+--------------------->X
```

What about the following case?

```
Y
|    o          o
|    o          o
|     o        oo
|     o         o
|    oo         o
|    o          o 
|    o          o
| o oo o oo oo o o o oo
+--------------------->X
    x1          x2
```

Basically, the scatter plot show strong clustering and spikes around a few data point along X axis, e.g. x1 and x2.

**What kind of statistical property does this imply?**

Comment: Incidentally, can you link to the article in question? (The figure you're making could be caused by a couple of explanations, but it depends on the specific data).

Comment: For example, depending on what the figure specifically looks like, `x` and `y` could be entirely independent. Try running `plot(rnorm(20000, rep(1:2, each=10000), .2),  rlnorm(20000, 0, .8))` in R. It'll look roughly similar to your figure, even though `x` and `y` are perfectly independent.

Comment: @DavidRobinson, sorry the article is still under review and not publicly available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correlation between X and Y measures the presence or absence of a **linear** relationship between them. If y=aX+B -- a pure line with no scatter and no error - the correlation will be 1 (if a>0) and -1 (if a < 0). It is not a general measure of causality or relatedness.

Your second scatter plot shows no linearity at all. A correlation is not an appropriate measure in this case.

Comment: Your clarification on the term "correlation" <--> linear relationship is correct. It shows a relationship, just not the correlation. I am still trying to find the right way to describe the relationship though.

Comment: It looks like a mixture model: 2 tight distributions centered around X1 and X2 respectively. That's all I can say, since I don't know where the numbers come from. It doesn't look as if knowing a Y value helps you predict X - or vice versa.

Answer (score 6):

The pattern you describe is completely uncorrelated but can be picked up with some information theoretic measure such as [mutual information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information). There are a number of packages implementing it, e.g. [entropy](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/entropy/index.html) and [infotheo](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/infotheo/index.html).

There is also a quite recent dependency measure called [MIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_information_coefficient), implemented in java with an R wrapper that you can get at [www.exploredata.net](http://www.exploredata.net/). It has a bunch of nice properties such as being on the [0, 1] interval and not favoring any particular type of relationship (e.g. linear) over others. It is not entirely uncontroversial though, so I recommend reading the orgignal article by [Reshef *et al*](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22174245) (Science 2012).

Comment: thanks for the references. Now I think about it, X Y does have a correlation, it is just not conventional "linear" type. I don't know the statistic term for this, maybe the article you referred will shed some light to it. thx

Comment: Yes, regardless of if it's called "correlation" or something else, X and Y are certainly not independent.